# Javascript inserting html code without closing tags

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of table columns. I would like to display them in one row.

What am I trying is :

```js
for (var i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
    writeToScreen3('<div class="col-sm">' + key[i] + '</div>'); //column name
}
```

```js
function writeToScreen3(message) {
    var pre = document.createElement("p"); //I realize I am creating another element <p> How to do it diffrently?
    pre.innerHTML = message;
    output.appendChild(pre);
}
```

What I need is this transferred to JavaScript :

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I also tried :

```js
function test8() {
    $("#output").html('<div class="container">< div class= "row" >'); //but it always closes these 2 divs here . I want it not to close it. output is a div field
}
```

Comment: where is `output`?
are you mixing `<p>` with `<pre>`?

Comment: output is ```<div id="output">```

Comment: How can I not ```createElement``` for example? Or just place <div> tags without closing them, then display columns names, and then close it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
function createContainer(columns) {
  function createDivWithClass(cls) {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.classList.add(cls);
    return div;
  }

  const container = createDivWithClass('container');
  const row = createDivWithClass('row');

  container.appendChild(row);

  for (let i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    const column = createDivWithClass('col-sm');
    column.textContent = columns[i];

    row.appendChild(column);
  }

  return container;
}

const container = createContainer([1, 2, 3, 4]);

document.getElementById('output').appendChild(container);

console.log(container.outerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Here, I've defined a function called `createDivWithClass` to make it easier to create a `<div>` and set a class name to it.

Then, I'm using this function to create a `<div class="container">`, create a `<div class="row">` and add that to the container, and then go through the `columns` array and create `<div class="col-sm">` and add those to the `row` element.

Just like you can append elements to the `#output` element in the DOM, you can also append elements to elements that you've created and are not yet in the DOM.